# ASPX Codebehind - Changing SelectCommand causes sorting to revert to original data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a GridView attached to a SQLDatasource, it works fine, and I can sort it properly with the original data.

If I tell the codebehind to find specific information via a pre-defined SQLDataSource on the ASPX page (SqlDataSource2), subsequent sorting works properly.

If I tell the codebehind to modify a pre-existing sqldatasource and bind that, subsequent sorting does not work properly, but returns original data.

Prereq:
SQL Data source connectionstring defined in Web.config, with id, last_modified, and view_count columns in table document_index.

ASPX:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"       Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />


        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT id, last_modified, view_count FROM [document_index] ORDER by id" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" /> 
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            SelectCommand= "SELECT id, last_modified, view_count FROM [document_index] WHERE view_count LIKE '7'"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" /> 
<div>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Select View Using ASPX SQL Source2 (Sort Works)" OnClick="aspxviewchange" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Select View Using Codebehind SQL Source1 Change Data (Sort Breaks)" OnClick="cbviewchange" />

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks= "true" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" Padding="20" DataKeyNames="id" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="25" AllowCustomPaging="True">

                <Columns>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            CreateNewColumn("last_modified", "Last Modified");
            CreateNewColumn("view_count", "Views");
        }
    }
    protected void CreateNewColumn(string SQLcolname, string header)
    {
        BoundField NewColumnName = new BoundField();
        NewColumnName.DataField = SQLcolname;
        NewColumnName.SortExpression = SQLcolname;
        NewColumnName.HeaderText = header;
        GridView1.Columns.Add(NewColumnName);
    }
    protected void aspxviewchange(object sender, EventArgs e)  // SUBSEQUENT SORTING WORKS
    {
        GridView1.DataSourceID = "SQLDataSource2";   
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void cbviewchange(object sender, EventArgs e) // SUBSEQUENT SORTING BROKEN
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT id, last_modified, view_count FROM [document_index] WHERE view_count LIKE '7'";
        GridView1.DataSourceID = "SQLDataSource1";
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Selecting the ASPX SQL button sorts properly, and subsequent sorting works.
Selecting the Codebehind SQL button sorts properly, but subsequent sorting does not work.

Comment: You haven't posted enough code. Basically it depends where this code is executing in the page event life cycle, which is archaic and difficult to explain. I would recommend posting your entire code behind if at all possible.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original post and posted the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to work around the issue by using IF/BEGIN/END/ELSE IF clauses in a single SQL statement based on my codebehind parameter.  It seems like the best way to go, considering dynamically changing the select command leads to other issues.

Answer (score 0):

> but subsequent sorting does not work

The Reason why the subsequent sorting does not work is that you are re-submitting the page and the Grid is rebinding to the Default datasource (`DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`) .

You will have to capture which is the datasource that is "sending" the SORT reguest and rebind the grid

something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)  
    {
         //capture SORT request (which View?)
         string RequestType = (get the grid request type);  
         if(RequestType  = "SortView1")
         {
             GridView1.datasourceID = datasource1; 
             GridView1.DataBind();
         }
         else if(RequestType  = "SortView2")
         {
             GridView1.datasourceID = datasource2; 
             GridView1.DataBind();
         }

    }
    else
    {
       GridView1.datasourceID = datasource1; 
       GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could (over)write your own 'onGridView1Submit' method

Either way, you should also remove the default Datasource `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"` in the Grid Control

Comment: The ASPX GridView does not have a Rebind property, so GridView1.Rebind(); will not work.  Unless I need to use an additional library, and if so, please elaborate.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I am just used to a third party vender that does expose a Rebind() method (for asp.net Grids).
Most importantly just wanted to convey the logic that was causing the behavior you were seeing. That is one of the trickiest part of Webforms. Getting used to when evnts happen and which sequence.
I added some more code but didn't write all the conditional logic getting which sort request was made, but let e know if you fill out that code on your own. I will try to assist. Good Luck!

Comment: Has this worked out for you? Let me know, if any further assistance needed?

Comment: Not quite, for example, I'm unsure of the code to put in your placeholder      "(get the grid request type)".  And also, I want the datasourceid to technically always bind with SQLDataSource1, only with different select command parameters, but doing it that way causes the sorting issue.

Comment: The code you posted shows that you are trying to reset the data source dynamically.
Resetting the Select parameter is the better way to do it. If you want to go that route you can add "CommandName" and "CommandValue" to your buttons

Comment: I am trying to reset the data source dynamically.  The reason for this is so I don't need to have 10 different data sources on the ASPX page just for different select commands.  I guess I can consolidate the sources down a bit by using very elaborate SQL commands if need be, but I am indeed attempting to "update" the data source dynamically.